# Boots normally, but GRUB/BIOS screens do not appear

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, bios

A little bit of a weird situation here- I installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my new laptop a month or so ago and completely wiped the Windows partitions/disk during the install to make way for the glory that is Ubuntu. Everything works fine.

However, neither GRUB, nor the option to boot into BIOS appear when I boot. I simply get a blank black screen for 5-10 seconds, and then the little "ubuntu" text with loading dots appear, after which I arrive in my login screen. Although this works great, I would like to change this so that GRUB and the option to boot into BIOS appear (I seem to recall that I can do this from GRUB) every time I boot.

Anyhow, let me know if there are any solutions I can use to solve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable GRUB hidden timeout.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install gksu  

gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Place a `#` in front of `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

So that it reads `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Save the change and close the file.

Now execute this command :

```
sudo update-grub
```

You should see GRUB when booting the PC now.

Comment: As a side note: `/etc/grub.d/00_header: # Handle the deprecated GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT scheme.` — from Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Also You can define time You preffer to see GRUB loader when booting changeing from 0 to Your set in seconds. But remember to not comment this line in Your configuration file.

Besides don't worry - BIOS is written in different type of memory than Your stored earlier Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to seeing your BIOS boot info, you probably have the Quiet or Fast/Quick BIOS option turned ON. I had one that called this Logo or Boot Image.

When you boot, quickly and repetitively hit the Del or F2 key (depends on the BIOS manufacturer, I think some use F1 as well). The BIOS screen should appear at some point.

In the BIOS screens, look for something like I mentioned above. The labeling changes depending on the manufacturer... Then try the usual Save & Exit. Now you should see the BIOS boot info on each reboot.